# Exclude '-1.79769313486232E+308' from table using select query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

I want to get the average of the data in one of the table but I get "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type float." exception. My table looks like,
[image]

I have to get the average of floating points in the table.
I want to exclude '-1.79769313486232E+308' from the table. How to do that?

Query that I have,

```
SELECT PS.Name, Z.[Round]
      ,AVG(Z.[EstimatedValue])
      ,AVG(Z.[InformationGain])
  FROM [dbo].[IntermediateScores] Z
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[PScale] PS
  ON Z.[ScaleId] = PS.Id
  GROUP BY PS.Name, Z.[Round]
  ORDER BY PS.Name,Z.[Round]
```

Comment: Can you include the actual SQL query you are running, and also tell us which _version_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: Probably one of the rare cases where `where isnumeric() = 0` would actually be useful.

Comment: I believe `-1.79769313486232E+308` is/was actually `1.7976931348623157e+30` and you copied the "displayed" value.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are running SQL Server (which the syntax of your query and the error message that you showed tend to indicate), you could use [`TRY_CAST()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  to handle values that do not fit in the `FLOAT` datatype. When the conversion fails, `TRY_CAST()` returns `NULL`, which aggregate function `AVG()` ignores.

```
SELECT 
    PS.Name, 
    Z.[Round],
    AVG(TRY_CAST(Z.[EstimatedValue] AS FLOAT)),
    AVG(TRY_CAST(Z.[InformationGain] AS FLOAT))
FROM [dbo].[IntermediateScores] Z
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PScale] PS ON Z.[ScaleId] = PS.Id
GROUP BY PS.Name, Z.[Round]
ORDER BY PS.Name,Z.[Round]
```

In general, you want to avoid relying on implicit conversion; it seems like your data is not stored in a numeric datatype, which is the root cause of your problem. Explicit conversion is a better practice, since it is easier to debug when things go wrong.